# http timing stats from tcp trace

Tags: http, tcpdump, pcap, statistics

I am trying to find a tool to extract HTTP timing stats from network traces; namely time to connect, time to first byte, total time to serve.
I am talking about very large traces with millions of requests.
Ideally I would like to generate Apache access log style record for each request, with timestamp, client IP, method, URL etc. in addition to mentioned timers, so the logs can be fed to existing access log analytic systems.
It seems like common necessity yet I can't find any free or commercial tool capable of doing it.
Is there any tools out there to achieve this goal ?

Comment: if the traces are cleartext, why don't you just use regex do extract the data yourself and then write a small script?

Comment: Traces are in standard pcap format.